# What is the reason behind cbegin/cend?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, const-correctness, const-iterator

I wonder why `cbegin` and `cend` were introduced in C++11?

What are cases when calling these methods makes a difference from const overloads of `begin` and `end`?

Answer (score 254, accepted):

It's quite simple. Say I have a vector:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
```

I fill it with some data. Then I want to get some iterators to it. Maybe pass them around. Maybe to `std::for_each`:

```
std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), SomeFunctor());
```

In C++03, `SomeFunctor` was free to be able to *modify* the parameter it gets. Sure, `SomeFunctor` could take its parameter by value or by `const&`, but there's no way to *ensure* that it does. Not without doing something silly like this:

```
const std::vector<int> &vec_ref = vec;
std::for_each(vec_ref.begin(), vec_ref.end(), SomeFunctor());
```

Now, we introduce `cbegin/cend`:

```
std::for_each(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(), SomeFunctor());
```

Now, we have syntactic assurances that `SomeFunctor` cannot modify the elements of the vector (without a const-cast, of course). We explicitly get `const_iterator`s, and therefore `SomeFunctor::operator()` will be called with `const int &`. If it takes it's parameters as `int &`, C++ will issue a compiler error.

---

C++17 has a more elegant solution to this problem: [`std::as_const`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/as_const). Well, at least it's elegant when using range-based `for`:

```
for(auto &item : std::as_const(vec))
```

This simply returns a `const&` to the object it is provided.

Comment: I thought the new protocol was cbegin(vec) rather than vec.cbegin().

Comment: @Kaz: There are no `std::cbegin/cend` free functions the way that `std::begin/std::end` exist. It was an oversight by the committee. If those functions did exist, that would generally be the way to use them.

Comment: Apparently, `std::cbegin/cend` will be added in C++14. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin

Comment: @NicolBolas is `for(auto &item : std::as_const(vec))` equivalent to `for(const auto &item : vec)`?

Comment: @luizfls Yes. Your code says the item will not be modified by putting the `const` on the reference. Nicol's views the container as const, so `auto` deduces a `const` reference. IMO `auto const& item` is easier and clearer. It's unclear why `std::as_const()` is good here; I can see it'd be useful when passing something non-`const` to generic code where we can't control the type that gets used, but with range-`for`, we can, so it just seems like added noise to me there.

Comment: There always has been `const_cast` for pre-C++17. These methods are completely unnecessary and they just pollute this already polluted language.

Comment: @mip: "*There always has been const_cast for pre-C++17.*" Which requires doing this: `const_cast<TypeOfVariable const>(variable)` rather than the much shorter `std::as_const(variable)`. I know which one I'd rather read. Also performing a `const_cast` on an iterator is 100% useless.

Comment: I meant `cbegin` and `cend` are unnecessary methods and even without `std::as_const` you could enforce const with `const_cast`. You don't need "silly reference". First part of your answer is simply wrong. Why `const_cast` on iterator is 100% useless?

Comment: @mip: "*Why `const_cast` on iterator is 100% useless?*" Because iterators don't propagate `const`-ness to their contents. That's why `iterator` and `const_iterator` are permitted to be different types. `templatename<T const>`, as far as the language is concerned, is a different type from `templatename<T>`, even though they are generated by the same template. Therefore, to allow an iterator to permit only `const`-access, the `const_iterator` for a container will need to be a different type from `iterator`.

Comment: Because iterators don't propagate constness it's not making `const_cast` 100% useless. Consider two overloaded methods `f(const iterator &)`  and `f(iterator &)`. How to force the first one on non-const `iterator`? Yes, it's very specific example, but you are making very broad statement. Also the point was that you could use `const_cast` instead of `std::as_const` and that your satement "In C++03 ... there's no way to ensure that it does" is wrong.

Comment: @mip: "*Yes, it's very specific example, but you are making very broad statement.*" I consider "100% useless" and "100% useless except for edge cases that serve no useful purpose" to be equivalent statements. "*that your satement "In C++03 ... there's no way to ensure that it does" is wrong.*" There was another sentence following that one, which explains that there are exceptions, and it even provides such an example. If you're just going to stop reading when you see a sentence you don't agree with, you're going to find yourself very disappointed.

Comment: I could give you more practical examples, but the comment section is pretty narrow. If you claim that C++17 has the solution, then C++03 also has the solution, because `const_cast` is exactly that - a slightly more verbose version of `std::as_const`. Maybe I should mention C-style casts as well - they can be also used to add or remove `const`.

Answer (score 71):

Beyond what Nicol Bolas said in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12001519/334761), consider the new `auto` keyword:

```
auto iterator = container.begin();
```

With `auto`, there's no way to make sure that `begin()` returns a constant operator for a non-constant container reference. So now you do:

```
auto const_iterator = container.cbegin();
```

Comment: Couldn't you do const auto const_iterator = container.begin()?

Comment: @allyourcode: Doesn't help.  To the compiler, `const_iterator` is just another identifier.  Neither version uses a lookup of the usual member typedefs `decltype(container)::iterator` or `decltype(container)::const_iterator`.

Comment: @aschepler I don't understand your second sentence, but I think you missed the "const" in front of "auto" in my question. Whatever auto comes to, seems that const_iterator should be const.

Comment: @allyourcode: That would give you an iterator which is constant, but that's very different from an iterator to constant data.

Comment: There is a simple way of ensuring that you get a `const_iterator` with `auto`: Write an auxiliary function template called `make_const` to qualify the object argument.

Comment: Maybe I'm just not in the C++ mindset anymore, but I can't see a connection between the concepts of "a simple way" and "write an auxiliary function template". ;)

Comment: @Columbo: Why write one, when there's now [`std::as_const`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/as_const). So `std::as_const(vec).begin()` and `vec.cbegin()` are equivalent

Comment: @allyourcode When you use `const auto const_iterator = container.begin()` it will create a top-level constant and not a low-level constant, as clearly mentioned by @aschepler

Comment: Even before `std::as_const` you could use `const_cast<>` on the right hand. They have polluted standard library with completely unnecessary methods and now we have ridiculous amount of functions that just return iterator to confuse young programmers....

Answer (score 15):

Take this as a practical usecase

```
void SomeClass::f(const vector<int>& a) {
  auto it = someNonConstMemberVector.begin();
  ...
  it = a.begin();
  ...
}
```

The assignment fails because `it` is a nonconst iterator. If you used cbegin initially, the iterator would have had the right type.

Answer (score 8):

From http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1674.pdf:

> so that a programmer can directly obtain a const_iterator from even a
>   non-const container

They gave this example

```
vector<MyType> v;

// fill v ...
typedef vector<MyType>::iterator iter;
for( iter it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it ) {
    // use *it ...
}
```

> However, when a container traversal is intended for inspection only,
>   it is a generally preferred practice to use a const_iterator in order
>   to permit the compiler to diagnose const-correctness violations

Note that the working paper also mentions adapter templates, that now have been finalized as `std::begin()` and `std::end()` and that also work with native arrays. The corresponding `std::cbegin()` and `std::cend()` are curiously missing as of this time, but they might also be added.

Answer (score 6):

Just stumbled upon this question... I know it's alredy answerd and it's just a side node...

`auto const it = container.begin()` is a different type then `auto it = container.cbegin()`

the difference for `int[5]` (using pointer, which i know don't have the begin method but show nicely the difference... but would work in c++14 for `std::cbegin()` and `std::cend()`, which is essentially what one should use when it's here)...

```
int numbers = array[7];
const auto it = begin(numbers); // type is int* const -> pointer is const
auto it = cbegin(numbers);      // type is int const* -> value is const
```

Answer (score 2):

`iterator` and `const_iterator` have inheritance relationship and an implicit conversion occurs when compared with or assigned to the other type.

```
class T {} MyT1, MyT2, MyT3;
std::vector<T> MyVector = {MyT1, MyT2, MyT3};
for (std::vector<T>::const_iterator it=MyVector.begin(); it!=MyVector.end(); ++it)
{
    // ...
}
```

Using `cbegin()` and `cend()` will increase performance in this case.

```
for (std::vector<T>::const_iterator it=MyVector.cbegin(); it!=MyVector.cend(); ++it)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: It took me a while to realise you meant performance is saved by avoiding conversion when initialising & comparing iterators, not the popular myth that `const`'s main benefit is performance (which it isn't: it's semantically correct and safe code). But, while you have a point, (A) `auto` makes that a non-issue; (B) in talking about performance, you missed a main thing you should've done here: cache the `end` iterator by declaring a copy of it in the init-condition of the `for` loop, & compare to that, instead of getting a new copy by value for every iteration. That'll make your point better. :P

Comment: @underscore_d `const` can definitely help achieve better performance, not because of some magic in the `const` keyword itself but because the compiler can enable some optimizations if it knows that the data won't be modified, which would not be possible otherwise. Check [this bit](https://youtu.be/zBkNBP00wJE?t=1613) from a Jason Turner's talk for a live example of this.

Comment: @brainplot I didn't say it couldn't. I said that's not its main benefit and that I think it gets overstated, when the real benefit of it is semantically correct and safe code.

Comment: @underscore_d Yes, I agree on that. I was just making it explicit that `const` can (almost indirectly) lead to performance benefits; just in case somebody reading this may think "I won't bother adding `const` if the generated code isn't affected in any way ever", which is not true.

Answer (score 0):

its simple,
cbegin returns a constant iterator where begin returns just an iterator

for better understanding lets take two scenarios here

scenario - 1 :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <vector>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
std::vector<int> v;

for (int i = 1; i < 6; ++i)
{
    /* code */
    v.push_back(i);
}

for(auto i = v.begin();i< v.end();i++){
    *i = *i + 5;
}

for (auto i = v.begin();i < v.end();i++){
    cout<<*i<<" ";
}

return 0;
}
```

this will run because here iterator i is not constant and can be incremented by 5

now let's use cbegin and cend denoting them as constant iterators 
scenario - 2 :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <vector>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
std::vector<int> v;

for (int i = 1; i < 6; ++i)
{
    /* code */
    v.push_back(i);
}

for(auto i = v.cbegin();i< v.cend();i++){
    *i = *i + 5;
}

for (auto i = v.begin();i < v.end();i++){
    cout<<*i<<" ";
}

return 0;
}
```

this is not going to work, because you cant update the value using cbegin and cend which returns the constant iterator