# Return correct type of iterator for a linked list

Tags: c++, iterator, linked-list

I'm implementing a generic list: List with two types of iterators: `List<T>::Iterator` and `List<T>ConstIterator`.

I have the following methods:

```
typename List<T>::Iterator List<T>::begin() {}
typename List<T>::ConstIterator List<T>::begin() const {}
```

Is this is the appropriate way to return non constant iterator for a non constant list and a constant iterator for a constant list?

Comment: Why do people reinvent anything? Learning things would be a good answer, but, please study and grasp (and reimplement(!)) existing things first, please!

Comment: I don't re-implement things because I'm bored, I do because I'm writing a HW which not allows using STD.

Comment: Seriously, please don’t put tags in the title.

Comment: If you are building your own library for a platform that lacks of stl support, consider implementing subset of stl (i.e. same naming conversion, for example).

Comment: Also, it might be easier, porting a subset of STL (that is relevant to your HW ), than re-implementing the data structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's the way it is also done [in the standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/begin).

Similar to the standard library extensions introduced in C++ 11 you could additionally provide a `cbegin()` function that [allows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001410/what-is-the-reason-behind-cbegin-cend) to get a const iterator even if the list isn't const itself.