# Is there a way to use standalone `std::begin` and for a const_iterator?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, const-correctness

I like consistency. I recently asked the question of using `std::begin` vs. e.g. `std::vector<int>::begin`, and the unanimous decision seemed to be to use the former since it is more general. But I think I found a stick in the mud. Sometimes, you want to convey you will not change a container as you loop through it, hence calling `std::vector<int>::cbegin`. It would make your code quite asymmetric if you sometimes did `iter = v.cbegin()` and other times did `iter = begin(v)`. Is there a way around this lack of symmetry, and would you still recommend `std::begin` given this knowledge? Why does C++ not have `std::cbegin`?

Comment: Note: C++ will have `std::cbegin` come C++14.

Comment: "Why does C++ not have ___" 1) Nobody wanted it enough to do it. 2) It doesn't fit well within C++'s principles (don't pay for what you don't use, don't assume much about the platform, etc.) 3) Time constraints. 4) Oversight. In your case, likely 4.

Comment: Last year Nicolas Bolas said it was an oversight: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001410/what-is-the-reason-behind-cbegin-cend#comment16015196_12001519 Not sure if that's true but it's quite likely.

Comment: @GManNickG - I think it's useful to know which one of the four it is.  "Doesn't fit with the principles" means it will never be there.  "Oversight" or "time constraint" mean there's a good chance it will get in to the standard sooner or later.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

C++14 has `cbegin`/`cend`/etc. and it is starting to be available in major compilers.

Comment: and by "etc" Herb means: `cbegin/cend/rbegin/rend/crbegin/crend`

Answer (score 3):

When your container is declared "const", for example, it is passed to a function as `foo(const std::vector<int> & v)`, then `std::begin` will actually return a `const_iterator`.

Comment: Right... but that isn't really the issue here. E.g. if I used a container with `std::find`, I would use `std::cbegin` and `std::cend` to be consistent even for a non`const` container.