# What is the difference between cbegin and begin for vector?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator

The member [begin](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/begin/) has two overloadings one of them is `const_iterator begin() const;`. There's also the [cbegin](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/cbegin/) `const_iterator cbegin() const noexcept;`. Both of them returns `const_iterator` to the begin of a list. What's the difference?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

`begin` will return an `iterator` or a `const_iterator` depending on the const-qualification of the object it is called on.

`cbegin` will return a `const_iterator` unconditionally.

```
std::vector<int> vec;
const std::vector<int> const_vec;

vec.begin(); //iterator
vec.cbegin(); //const_iterator

const_vec.begin(); //const_iterator
const_vec.cbegin(); //const_iterator
```

Comment: That's it? So in fact, we have two functions behaving completely the same on const objects... Does it reslly make a sense?

Comment: It's for flexibility. If you know you need a `const_iterator`, call `cbegin`. If you know you need an `iterator`, call `begin` and you'll get an error if  it's not valid. If you don't care, call `begin`.

Comment: @user3663882: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001410/what-is-the-reason-behind-cbegin-cend

Comment: What is the difference between `const_iterator` and `iterator`

Comment: @Asadefa - check out the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/309589/11265473)

Answer (score 37):

`begin()` returns an `iterator` to beginning while `cbegin()` returns a `const_iterator` to beginning.

The basic difference between these two is `iterator` (i.e `begin()`) lets you change the value of the object it is pointing to and `const_iterator` will not let you change the value of the object.

For example:

This IS allowed. The vector values change to `{0,10,20,30,40}`:

```
vector<int> v{10,20,30,40,50};
vector<int> :: iterator it;

for (it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++)
{
    *it = *it - 10;
}
```

This is NOT allowed. It will throw an error:

```
for (it = v.cbegin(); it != v.cend(); it++)
{
    *it = *it - 10;
}
```

Comment: The second code is not producing error. It is working fine i tried it.

Comment: @Proton I does not compile. It must and will fail at the assignment operator as it can not have a semantically valid overload for anything `const`.

Comment: `begin()` does not always return `iterator`: it depends on the const-ness of its container. If that container is const, `begin` will return `const_iterator` instead of `iterator`.