# Converting vector<>::const_iterator to vector<>::iterator

Tags: c++, vector, casting, iterator

I am coding my very own vector container. To do so, I have a vector class and a `RAIterator` (Random Access Iterator) class. In my vector class I am implementing all of std::vector member functions. Amongst them is `begin()` which returns an iterator to the first element of the vector. There is also an overload which returns a constant iterator. My functions look like this:

```
iterator        begin() { return (iterator(_data)); }
const_iterator  begin() const { return (const_iterator(_data)); }
```

Here `iterator` and `const_iterator` are the same as in iterator_traits. My main looks like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    ft::vector<int> v;

    ft::vector<int>::iterator it2 = v.begin();
    ft::vector<int>::const_iterator it = v.begin();
}
```

`ft` is the namespace I am using to create my vector. The first call to `v.begin()` is alright but the second is not. This is because the first `begin()` function is called both times and since it returns `iterator`, the compiler tells me that there is no available conversion from `iterator` to `const_iterator`. Here is the actual error I receive:

```
main.cpp:70:34: error: no viable conversion from 'RAIterator<ft::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >::pointer>' to
      'RAIterator<ft::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >::const_pointer>'
        ft::vector<int>::const_iterator it = v.begin();
                                        ^    ~~~~~~~~~
./iterators/RAIterator.hpp:49:9: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'ft::vector<int,
      std::__1::allocator<int> >::iterator' (aka 'RAIterator<int *>') to 'const int *' for 1st argument
        RAIterator(T src) : _ptr(src) { /*std::cout << "Second constructor called" << std::endl;*/ }
        ^
./iterators/RAIterator.hpp:50:9: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'ft::vector<int,
      std::__1::allocator<int> >::iterator' (aka 'RAIterator<int *>') to 'const ft::RAIterator<const int *> &' for 1st argument
        RAIterator(const RAIterator &src) : _ptr(src._ptr) { /*std::cout << "Third constructor called" << std::endl;*/ } // CHANGE
        ^
1 error generated.
```

Here are my `RAIterator` class constructors:

```
RAIterator() : _ptr(NULL) { /*std::cout << "First constructor called" << std::endl;*/ }
RAIterator(T src) : _ptr(src) { /*std::cout << "Second constructor called" << std::endl;*/ }
RAIterator(const RAIterator &src) : _ptr(src._ptr) { /*std::cout << "Third constructor called" << std::endl;*/ } // CHANGE
```

I don't know how to solve this problem, i.e. how to make this conversion possible. If I write `std` instead of `ft` it compiles correctly, so I have to be able to support this conversion.

**P.S.** I have to use C++98. Weird, right?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a converting constructor.

In C++98 there aren't all the helpful traits to only allow the template constructor when `T` is pointer to const, and `U` is the corresponding pointer to mutable, so it will always participate in overload resolution, but instantiating it will fail for incompatible pointer types.

```
template<typename T>
class RAIterator {
    T _ptr;
public:
    RAIterator() : _ptr(nullptr) {}
    RAIterator(T src) : _ptr(src) {}
    RAIterator(const RAIterator &src) : _ptr(src._ptr) {}
    template<typename U>
    // requires std::same_as<std::remove_pointer_t<T>, const std::remove_pointer_t<U>>
    RAIterator(const RAIterator<U> &src) : _ptr(src._ptr) {}

    // all your existing stuff
};
```

Answer (score 1):

C++ does not support function overloading based on return types, only on argument types (where `this` is also considered an argument). So there is no way for the compiler to distinguish the two `v.begin()` calls.

If you call `begin()` on a `const` object, you'll see that it calls the `const` overload:

```
    ft::vector<int> const &const_v = v;
    ft::vector<int>::const_iterator it = const_v.begin();
```

But that is a bit silly, of course.

In C++11, `cbegin` and `cend` were [added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001410/what-is-the-reason-behind-cbegin-cend) to make this easier.

But why does it work unmodified in `std::vector`? I can't find any documentation on this, but I think the reason must be that `std::vector::iterator` supports implicit conversion to `std::vector::const_iterator`.

Comment: Thank you. How could I code this implicit conversion?

Comment: Either as an implicit conversion operator on `iterator` or as an implicit conversion constructor on `const_iterator`. You can do a web search for these terms.

Comment: The think is that I do not have an iterator class or a const_iterator class. I just have a RAIterator class which is a template and the parameter I pass onto the template is either iterator or const_iterator

Comment: Then add an implicit conversion from `RAIterator<iterator>` to `RAIterator<const_iterator>`. Some template trickery might be needed. Or open a new question with the relevant code if you can't figure it out.